# Get Lambda Arn into Resources : Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have the following in my serverless yml file :

```
lambdaQueueFirstInvokePermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    FunctionName: ServiceLambdaFunctionQualifiedArn
    Action: ‘lambda:InvokeFunction’
    Principal: sqs.amazonaws.com
```

and I have the following in the Outputs section :

```
Outputs:
  ServiceLambdaFunctionQualifiedArn:
  Value:
    ‘Fn::GetAtt’: [ lambdaQueueFirst, Arn ]
```

this comes back with a message:
 `Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource lambdaQueueFirst`

Am I missing something and if so, what? since it is very little in terms of help or examples…
Also, is there a better of getting the lambda arn into the permissions code? if so, what is it?

Comment: Show your `Type: AWS::Serverless::Function` resource

Comment: Where is your `lambdaQueueFirst` resource?

Comment: Hi.  thanks to both of you on your replies.  The function is under the "function" section on the serverless.yml file.  its not in the resources section.  is it still possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the environment variables to construct the ARN value. In your case, you can define a variable in your provider section like below. You might need to modify a little bit according to your application.

```
service: serverless App2
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.6
  region: ap-southeast-2
  stage: dev
  environment:
    AWS_ACCOUNT: 1234567890 # use your own AWS ACCOUNT number here

    # define the ARN of the function that you want to invoke
    FUNCTION_ARN: "arn:aws:lambda:${self:provider.region}:${self:provider.environment.AWS_ACCOUNT}:function:${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-lambdaQueueFirst" 

Outputs:
ServiceLambdaFunctionQualifiedArn:
Value: "${self:provider.environment.FUNCTION_ARN}"
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44036642/5097630) and [serverless variables for aws](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    LoggingLambdaPermission:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      Properties:
        FunctionName: { "Fn::GetAtt": ["LoghandlerLambdaFunction", "Arn" ] }
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        Principal: { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["logs.", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region"}, ".amazonaws.com" ] ] }
```

reference:
https://github.com/andymac4182/serverless_example

Comment: this works for me. i can get the `Arn` of the lambda function inside the `Resources` section using `{ "Fn::GetAtt": ["LoghandlerLambdaFunction", "Arn" ] }`